# Could not access image from download folder

Tags: android, uri, internal-storage

I am facing a weird scenario where I have 5 images when I opened intent from app  [link_for_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCQrO.jpg) , for except the circled image remaining images I am able to get the path,  I was getting below error for circled image mentioned in above link,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/edcd36b47bdf6e9e045c72250a8bbd24.jpg
```

In downloads folder(when opened from File Manager) the circled image is not available, what could be the issue, here is the logic for retrieving image path

```
 String fileName = getFilePath(context, uri);
 if (fileName != null) {
     return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
 }

 String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
 if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
     id = id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
     File file = new File(id);
     if (file.exists())
         return id;
 }

 final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
 return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The image you trying to get is actually deleted from your storage & your `mediascanner` is unaware of it.

You can solve this by doing the following.

```
1 - Restart the phone. (*If issue still persist perform `2`)

2 - Clean & clear cache for `Gallary/Photos/File Manager`. 

3 - Perform a `mediascan` programatically.
```

Let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want you to think on behalf of user , which we cannot propose to him/her, so can you please let me know how can we solve this issue

Comment: go  with 3rd option, perform a media scan for that file...handle the exception carefully. I had the same problem at very beginning from our client..